# Tankless hot water heater connected inline to 4 gal point of use

Tags: plumbing

My idea is to install a light use tankless to  4 gal point of use tank directly to whole condo. The tankless is rated at 1.5gpm so I wanted to hook the outlet into a 4 gal point of use then to whole condo. The reasoning is I wont have to upgrade the wiring/breaker this way and ideally have sufficient hot water for a shower and sink combo. Does anybody see any problems with this setup. Thanks

Comment: What is the watt ratiing on the tankless? Is this an "electric shower" unit you found at an Internet vendor like Amazon?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to get the worst of everything:

- Not enough tank to get through even moderate usage, so the tankless will have to run a lot. Actually, it will need to run *any time* you use hot water, because as water flows out of the tiny storage tank, cold water will flow through the tankless and it will start heating right away.
- Extra point of failure. Instead of "one thing" you now have two things.

Unless you are extremely pressed for space, I recommend an ordinary storage tank heater. It will generally use a **lot** less power when running than even the smallest of on-demand heaters. It will run longer (working to reheat the tank after a shower), but the total energy usage will be in the same ballpark.

Comment: Tankless electric heaters are Just Plain Foolish. They have become a fad on the basis of utter misrepresentations and without consideration for their gigantic downsides. +1

Comment: There is nothing wrong with tankless if you have the amps. They are a misfit if you don't, but such misapplication is the fault of the user not the technology. Certainly it is more sensible to run aluminum feeder clear across a house than hot water pipe.  So multiple PoU tankless are best of all.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I agree. But OP stated "*I wont have to upgrade the wiring/breaker this way*", which I took to mean "don't have the amps" **and** "*to whole condo*". A 1.5 gpm would be reasonable *for each bathroom*, but not for 2 or more bathrooms or even 1 bathroom + kitchen.